# Can't S/MIME sign using OpenSSL even if "verify" suceeds

Tags: openssl, client-certificate, smime, x509, pkcs

I have a client certificate in Chrome, that I used for logging into StartSSL. I exported it using `pk12util` to `certfile.p12`. Now I want to use it for signing with S/MIME.

I converted the `p12` file to `pem`.

First, I verify that the certificate will work for this purpose:

```
$ openssl verify -purpose smimesign -verbose -CAfile ca-bundle.crt certfile.pem
certfile.pem: OK
```

Now I try and sign:

```
$ echo "lol" | openssl smime -sign -CAfile ca-bundle.crt -signer certfile.pem
unable to load signing key file
3074062600:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

If I use the original `p12`file, it doesn't work either, but with another error message:

```
$ openssl verify -purpose smimesign -verbose -CAfile ca-bundle.crt certfile.p12
unable to load certificate
3074066696:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

What should I do so that I can sign messages with free StartSSL certificates?

Comment: `cat` the file `certfile.pem`. It should have `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and friends. Also, the `openssl smime -sign` *might* not need `-CAfile ca-bundle.crt` since you are *not* verifying a signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot the `-nodes` flag when making the `pem`. This includes the private key.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certfile.p12 -nodes -out certfile2.pem
```

This `pem`can be used for signing.

Comment: You should probably mark your own answer as accepted so others know this was the fix.